# How to create this Custom Walker Menu

Tags: menus, walker

It's the first time I'm trying to create a customized menu Walker. I'm following a very specific HTML. I searched and tried different things. Days have passed and I still can't get it right, but I don't want to give up.

This is the HTML I'm trying to output:

```
<!-- <ul class="menu"> -->

  <li class="menu-item">
    <div class="contains-submenu">
      <span class="menu-title"><a href="www.link.com">Item</a></span>

      <div class="submenu">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-item">
    <div class="contains-submenu">
      <span class="menu-title"><a href="www.site.com/link">Item</a></span>

      <div class="submenu">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-item">
    <div class="contains-submenu">
      <span class="menu-title"><a href="www.link.com">Item</a></span>

      <div class="submenu">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

          <div class="submenu-item">
            <div style='background-image: url("www.site.com/icon")'></div>
            <p>Description</p>
            <a href="www.link.com">Item</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="menu-item">
    <div>
      <span class="menu-title"><a href="www.link.com">Item</a></span>
    </div>
  </li>

<!-- </ul> -->
```

This is my current attempt:

```
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

    if ($depth === 0) {
      $output .= "\n$indent<div class='submenu'>\n";
      $output .= "\n$indent<div class='container'>\n";
    }

  }

  function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

    if ($depth === 0) {
      $output .= "\n$indent</div></div>\n";
    }
    if ($depth === 1) {
      $output .= "\n$indent</div>\n";
    }

  }

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

    $attributes  = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= !empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= !empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    if ($depth === 0) {
      $output .= $indent . "<li class='menu-item'>\n";
      $output .= $indent . "<div class='contains-submenu'>";
      $item_output .= "<span class='menu-title'><a". $attributes .">";
      $item_output .= apply_filters("the_title", $item->title, $item->ID);
      $item_output .= "</a></span>";
    }

    if ($depth === 1) {
      $output .= $indent . "<div class='submenu-item'>\n";
      $output .= $indent . "<div style='background-image: url(\"" . $item->url . "\")></div>";
      $output .= $indent . "<p>" . $item->description ."</p>";
    }

    if ($depth === 2) {
      $item_output .= $indent . "<a". $attributes . "></a>";
    }

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

}
```

The menu structure on the WordPress admin area is like this:

```
Item
  Subitem ---> custom link that contains link for icon and description
    Child Item
    Child Item
    Child Item
  Subitem
    Child Item
    Child Item
Item
  Subitem
    Child Item

// and so on...
```

The **Items** and **Child Items** are simple links for pages.
The **Subitems** are custom links that contains an icon url and description.
There is no **Subitem** empty, without at least one **Child Item** inside it.